# Grep only the numbers from linux shell

Tags: regex, linux, shell, awk, grep

I have an curl output as below and i need to grep only the numbers from that output.

Curl Output

```
<h1>JVM</h1><p>Free Memory:2144.78 MB Total Memory:3072.00 MB Max Memory:3072.00 MB</p><table border="0">
```

Grep Command

```
 grep -o -i 'Max Memory:.*'  | awk  '{ print $3 }'
```

Output

```
MB</p><table
```

Expected Output : 3072.00

Similarly for Free Memory and Total Memory.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following in GNU `grep`.

```
grep -oP 'Total Memory:\K\S+' Input_file
```

***OR*** in case you want to match exact digits which are coming for memory value then try following:

```
grep -oP 'Total Memory:\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\s)' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using GNU `grep`'s `-o` and `-P` options firstly. To print only matched text and to enable PCRE regex flavor. Then in main `grep` program using regex to match `Total Memory:` to be searched followed by `\K` which means if previous match is found then forget the match. Then matching `\S+` means match everything non-space(s) before a space comes which will catch value for Total memory.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In case you want to get 3 values in output for free memory, max and total ones then try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v RS='(Free Memory:|Total Memory:|Max Memory:)[^[:space:]]+' 'RT{sub(/.*:/,"",RT);print RT}' Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** In case your output is not in an Input_file then you can use pipe to your previous command and then run this one.

Comment: this works perfectly , Thank you Verymuch. can you please explain me what does \K\S+ do here.

Comment: sorry , i got the explanation

Comment: @JijoJohn, Your welcome. `\K` means forget the matched part which is mentioned just before `\K` in this case `Total Memory:` and `\S+` catch all NON-Spaces so that value after `Total Memory:` which is `3072.00` should be caught.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `gnu grep` command to get all memory numbers in one command:

```sh
s='<h1>JVM</h1><p>Free Memory:2144.78 MB Total Memory:3072.00 MB Max Memory:3072.00 MB</p><table border="0">'
grep -oP '\w+ Memory:\K[\d.]+' <<< "$s"

2144.78
3072.00
3072.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `sed` to extract all the necessary details from the string:

```sh
fm=$(sed -n 's/.*Free Memory:\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p' file)
tm=$(sed -n 's/.*Total Memory:\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p' file)
mm=$(sed -n 's/.*Max Memory:\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p' file)
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/MXJ6fx):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='<h1>JVM</h1><p>Free Memory:2144.78 MB Total Memory:3072.00 MB Max Memory:3072.00 MB</p><table border="0">'
fm=$(sed -n 's/.*Free Memory:\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p' <<< "$s")
tm=$(sed -n 's/.*Total Memory:\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p' <<< "$s")
mm=$(sed -n 's/.*Max Memory:\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p' <<< "$s")
echo "fm=$fm, tm=$tm, mm=$mm"
# => fm=2144.78, tm=3072.00, mm=3072.00
```

*Details*:

- `-n` suppresses default line output
- `.*Free Memory:\([^ ]*\).*` - matches the whole line that contains

  - `.*` - any zero or more chars
  - `Free Memory:`  - a fixed string
  - `\([^ ]*\)` - Group 1 (`\1`): any zero or more non-space chars
  - `.*` - any zero or more chars
- `/\1/` - replaces the line matched with Group 1 value
- `p` - prints the result of the successful substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grep -o -i 'Max Memory:.*'  | cut -d ':' -f 2 |awk  '{ print $1 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
<h1>JVM</h1><p>Free Memory:2144.78 MB Total Memory:3072.00 MB Max Memory:3072.00 MB</p><table border="0">
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[0-9]+[.][0-9]+"}{print $1,$2,$3}' file.txt
```

output

```
2144.78 3072.00 3072.00
```

Explanation: I informed GNU `AWK` that field is 1 or more digits followed by literal `.` followed by 1 or more digits. I `print` 1st, 2nd, 3rd field. **Disclaimer**: I assume that you are interesting only in numbers which have single `.` inside. Note that `0` in `<table border="0">` is not detected. Feel free to adjust to your needs.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*